# Object not modifying on async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have the following code:

```
async.each(strategies, function (strategy, callback) {
    filterEventTypes(strategy.eventType, function (err, res) {
        strategy.filters = [];
        var filter = {};
        filter.eventTypeIds = res;
        strategy.filters.push(filter);
        console.log('filter:' + JSON.stringify(filter));
        console.log('strategy: ' + JSON.stringify(strategy));
        ret.push(strategy);
        callback(null, res);
    });
}, function (err) {
    err && callback(err, null);
    callback(null, ret);
});
```

filter outputs the following: `{"eventTypeIds":["1"]}`, however, the strategy object is not modified.

How can I modify the strategy object in order to add it to the ret array?

Comment: What does strategy object contains? Or do you want to extend it?

Comment: It's a simple JSON object, I want to extend it, add more properties.

Comment: Why are you ignoring errors? Why are you calling `callback` multiple times?! What is `ret`?

Answer (score 0):

strategy is a mongoose object, the query should be done with lean() function to return a javascript object.